# utf-8 using standard openStream and DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, rss

Need to convert the format of output to `UTF-8`, because the output is not treating special characters.
Anyone have any idea how can this be done?

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
URL u = new URL("http://www.aredacao.com.br/tv-saude");
Document doc = builder.parse(u.openStream());
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the site returns `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>` but it should be returning `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`.

One solution is to translate each element's text yourself:

```
static void readData()
throws IOException,
       ParserConfigurationException,
       SAXException {

    DocumentBuilder builder =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    URL u = new URL("http://www.aredacao.com.br/tv-saude");
    Document doc = builder.parse(u.toString());
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        Element el = (Element) node;

        String title =
            el.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
        title = treatCharsAsUtf8Bytes(title);

        String description =
            el.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
        description = treatCharsAsUtf8Bytes(description);

        System.out.println("title=" + title);
        System.out.println("description=" + description);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static String treatCharsAsUtf8Bytes(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Another possibility is to write a subclass of FilterInputStream which replaces the erroneous `<?xml` prolog's encoding, but that is a lot more work, and I would only consider doing that if the document had a complex structure with many different elements such that translating each would be unwieldy.